# how to execute and get the result from interactive command in go?

Tags: go

```
func main() {

    //r, w := io.Pipe()
    //r1, w1 := io.Pipe()
    cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
    in, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    out, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    go func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(in, "bbbb\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(in, "ccccc\n")
    }()
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(out)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Printf("data is %q \n", scanner.Text()) //it print nothing
        }
    }()
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

here is my code, I want to run an interactive command and get the result. and not to stop the command process, I wish it can always run.

I try set Stdout  to system, I will print the result. but I can't get it in code.

```
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

I try close output, but the application stop, but I hope it can always run.

```
go func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(in, "bbbb\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(in, "ccccc\n")
        in.Close()
}()
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your go code, the stdout is being buffered until the application ends. If you write enough data, you sill start to get output.

Comment: Separately, your program has no synchronization of the goroutines, so when the command does return, you may not see all the output before the your program exits.

Comment: Thanks, how can do the synchronization? I am a beginner. use channel?

Comment: A channel works, but a `sync.WaitGroup` is usually used especially when you have more than one goroutine.